# Unable to connect with database: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized'

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, invalidoperationexception

I am unable to connect my database from Sql-server in Visual studio for my school project. I've tried multiple solutions that didn't work... Hopefully you can help me out!

This is my ConnectionString in my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connString" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I have written my code to be able to open a connection to my database and check if the user-credentials in the login Window are right. When clicking on btnSubmit() with the right credentials (same as in the database), it should redirect to a new Window.

Only problem is that I always receive the same error at **conn.Open()** when running my solution:
**System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'**

This is my code for my login Window:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using MyClassLibrary;

namespace SlnProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Login.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Login : Window
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"];
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                String query = "SELECT COUNT(1) from [User] WHERE @login = login AND @password = paswoord";
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", txtName.Text);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    Main.Content = new WpfAdmin();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Foute ingave. Naam of passwoord is incorrect.");
                }
            }
        }
        private void btnKlant_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Main.Navigate(new WpfGebruiker());
        }
```

I also verified if my connection was working and there were no problems to be seen in Visual Studio.

Does someone know how to fix this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to change `AppSettings["connString"];` by `AppSettings["connectionString"];` ?

Comment: @McNets I tried this and it still gives me the same error being System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'

Comment: Use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString` instead of that.

Comment: When using your method I get this error instead: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' @GabrielNegut

Comment: `string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString;` gives you a `null` value for `connectionString` ? Please place a breakpoint on your `using` statement so that you can check.

Comment: @ChrisBD Yes I checked and the string connectionString gives me a null value.

Comment: Where is your app.config file? Is it in the same directory as your application debug build?

Comment: @ChrisBD I have a Class Library in the same project where my app.config is placed. The using: MyClassLibrary in the login Window refers to it. Even if my App.config is in the same solution it still gives me the NullReferenceException back... So to answer the question no the debug build is not in the same directory

Comment: When you build your application to debug it you need to ensure that an app.config file with the correct contents is copied to the same location as your debug application build is placed. Please check the solution debug output folder.

Comment: @ChrisBD I copied my app.config file in the same location as my debug app build but it still gives me the same Null exception. I even tried placing my App.config in the same location but also the same problem

Comment: Is this a desktop app? If it is not then the configuration will likely not be held within an app.config file. For example ASP.Net may use web.config

Comment: @ChrisBD it is a desktop app which is very disturbing because it should work like this and I don't know what other config I need to check/modify before it finally starts working

Comment: I'm wondering whether you have a threading or access issue. May I suggest that you try placing the connection string retrieval code in the main application code (say in the app start file) to see if it is read correctly from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following, tested with your settings.

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString;

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
}
```

Another thing to try, see if your connection string is there in the list with `Data` appended to the name e.g. `connStringData`

```
var settings = ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings
    .OfType<ConnectionStringSettings>().ToList();

for (int index = 0; index < settings.Count(); index++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{index,-3}{settings[index].Name,-10}{settings[index].ConnectionString}");
}
```

Alternate, change app.config to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="SqlServerConnection" value="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Usage

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlServerConnection"]))
{
    conn.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Opened");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work I already tried before @Karen Payne

Comment: @JadeG see my edited response.

Comment: I created a Console Project to test your code and this is my response: **0  LocalSqlServerdata source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true** So it doesn't show my connection string, any idea of how I can resolve this?

Comment: That does not make sense so see example 3 in my reply, other than that no other suggestions.